# Error: Program type already present: android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to android and facing below error in Android studio please help...!

Error: Program type already present: android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader

[see error img here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsgKN.png)

Thanks in advance...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below code in Build.gradle file

```
configurations.all { exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4' }
```

for more please check this video...
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N3Txd-Q4qhQ

Comment: Worked!Thank you.

Comment: when i put this code it shows me this error : > Could not get unknown property 'configration' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Comment: Sorry my mistake there was a typo in 'configrations.all' that should be 'configurations.all' ... now i updated my code.... please try above edited code... Thanks